# Como consultar cnpj utilizando HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, http-request

É o seguinte, estou criando um programa para realizar consultas de CPF e CNPJ no site da receita federal. Não é uma tentativa de burlar o sistema. Eu estou trazendo o captcha para um PictureBox para que o usuário possa apenas inserir os caracteres sem precisar digitar o cnpj ou cpf, que seriam preenchidos automaticamente.

A parte que realiza a consulta de CPF é mais simples, eu apenas preenchi os campos do cabeçalho http manualmente, definindo o cookie da sessão obtido na requisição do captcha. O problema está na consulta do CNPJ.

O site da receita federal envia uma requisição com o seguinte cabeçalho:

```
POST http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 111
DNT: 1
Host: www.receita.fazenda.gov.br
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: flag=1; ASPSESSIONIDAQDSBCCD=ENPHBBJDCNDBAFPALIEEGOPP; ASPSESSIONIDASDSBCCC=EJGNAFJDDFCIOBAHNIFCPEHC
```

Depois disso ele faz três outras requisições, com as informações do CNPJ consultado sendo trazidas após a terceira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu não estou conseguindo é reproduzir essa consulta com um HttpWebRequest, mesmo tendo definindo todos os headers.

```
private void consultarPessoaJuridica()
    {
        string postContent = "origem=comprovante"
                           + "&cnpj=60872504000123"
                           + "&txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br=" + textBoxCaptcha1.Text
                           + "&submit1=Consultar"
                           + "&search_type=cnpj";

        byte[] postBytesArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postContent);

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp");
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).Timeout = 10000;

        webRequest.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.5");
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", this.cookie + "; flag=1");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).ContentLength = postBytesArray.Length;
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).Referer = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp";
        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).KeepAlive = true;

        ((HttpWebRequest)webRequest).Host = "www.receita.fazenda.gov.br";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Get the request stream.
        using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Write data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(postBytesArray, 0, postBytesArray.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

Essa requisição aparece no Fiddler da seguinte forma:

```
POST http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQCSADDD=EGGPDBLDCBJEPHJJONMEHHCP; flag=1
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp
Host: www.receita.fazenda.gov.br
Content-Length: 111
Expect: 100-continue
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu acredito que isto esteja ocorrendo porque, por algum motivo, o código de status obtido após a segunda requisição é 200, não ocorrendo nenhum outro redirecionamento automático após isso.

Comment: Você vai redistribuir um recurso de um site, sem a permissão dele? pra mim isso se enquadra na definição da palavra "burlar".

Comment: Não seria a primeira vez que alguém faz isso com a Receita hahaa

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida no meu caso eu só queria agilizar a consulta sem perder muito tempo abrindo páginas e preenchendo formulários.

Comment: O que o @hideki.eduardo está tentando fazer já é amplamente utilizado por uma grande variedades de aplicações. Não tem nada haver com "burlar" é apenas uma forma de abstração, não vejo nenhuma forma de prejuízo para receita já que a mesma não ganha nada com a quantidade de acessos e visualizações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizando o System.Net.WebClient que é uma abstração do HttpWebRequest.

Recomendo não utilizar o AllowAutoRedirect.